# Bounding expectation of square roots

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value

Let $U, W \geq 0$, $U \leq W$ $\mathbb{P}( U < W) > 0$ and $\varepsilon > 0$ fix.

$\mathbf{Question:}$
Do we have
$$
\mathbb{E}[(\varepsilon + U)^{1/2}]^2 - \mathbb{E}[W^{1/2}]^2 \leq \varepsilon 
$$
?

$\mathbf{Ansatz:}$
By the third binomial formula, the left-hand side becomes
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[(\varepsilon + U)^{1/2} + W^{1/2}\right]\mathbb{E}\left[(\varepsilon + U)^{1/2} - W^{1/2}\right].
$$
Since $\mathbb{E}[X]\mathbb{E}[Y] = \mathbb{E}[XY] - \text{cov}(X, Y)$, this equals
\begin{align*}
&\mathbb{E}\left[\left((\varepsilon + U)^{1/2} + W^{1/2} \right) \left((\varepsilon + U)^{1/2} - W^{1/2} \right)\right] - \left( 
\mathbf{Var}((\varepsilon + U)^{1/2}) - \mathbf{Var}(W^{1/2})
\right) \\
= &\mathbb{E}[(\varepsilon + U)   - W] + \left( \mathbf{Var}(W^{1/2}) - 
\mathbf{Var}((\varepsilon + U)^{1/2})  \right) \\
=& \varepsilon + \mathbb{E}[U - W] + \left( \mathbf{Var}(W^{1/2}) - 
\mathbf{Var}((\varepsilon + U)^{1/2})  \right)
\end{align*}
This is smaller or equal than $\varepsilon$ if and only if
$$
\mathbf{Var}(W^{1/2}) - 
\mathbf{Var}((\varepsilon + U)^{1/2})
\leq \mathbb{E}[W - U],
$$
which does not seem to hold in general without any further assumptions on $U, W$. My assumption is therefore that the statement is wrong. I have tried to find counterexamples with two-point distributions but couldn't find one so far. I would therefore appreciate if someone managed to come up with a counterexample (or proof).

Thanks.